# On hook_entity_presave how do I know if it is a new node?

Tags: 8

I'm using the hook

```
function nvgh_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
}
```

but I only need to do something when the node is new (not when it is edited). How to do this? I'm inspecting the entity with kint but cannot find a good indicator for this... also kint is disappearing as the node view is redirected into view modes.

How to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`Entity::isNew()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3AisNew/8.5.x) method:

```
if ($entity->isNew()) {
  // ...
}
```